# Line Break in Radio Button xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, radio-button, line-breaks

i have a Problem in c# with the content of a radio button.
Because the Content is to long for one Line i need a Line break.

I've tried to do the LineBrek with "&#xa" but it's not working...
Thats my xaml:

```
<RadioButton x:Name="RbMitarbeiterNicht" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Margin="863,929,0,0"
             VerticalAlignment="Top"
             GroupName="rb_stoerung"
             Content="Mitarbeiter nicht anwesend"
             FontSize="16" Width="102" Foreground="#000000"
             Background="#FFFFFF" Checked="RbMitarbeiterNicht_Checked"/>
```

Comment: Have you tried using "\n" e.g. `Content="Mitarbeiter nicht \nanwesend"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have used `&#xa` instead of `&#x0a;` which is the line break unicode character.

If this is not the case and there is typo in the question then I suggest using a `TextBlock` for content.

```
<RadioButton x:Name="RbMitarbeiterNicht" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
         HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Margin="863,929,0,0"
         VerticalAlignment="Top"
         GroupName="rb_stoerung"
         FontSize="16" Width="102" Foreground="#000000"
         Background="#FFFFFF" Checked="RbMitarbeiterNicht_Checked">
    <RadioButton.Content>
        <TextBlock Text="Line 1 &#x0a;Line 2">
    </RadioButton.Content>
</RadioButton >
```

Comment: Yes thanks worked with ```&#x0a;``` I forgot to chenge the height. So i was not able to see the second row.... my Bad